# Implementing a nested generic in java

Tags: java, generics, interface

I have the following class

```
public class Element <T1 extends Comparable<T1>,T2> {
   public T1 key;
   public T2 value;
}
```

This compiles and works as I'd like.

I have an interface that I want to guarantee that all Elements in it have the same type.  But I want to specify that type in the class implementing the interface. So as an example, I might want the class that implements the interface to all be of the type `Element<String,Integer>`.

However, this won't compile

```
public interface D <Element<T1,T2>>  {
  ArrayList <Element<T1,T2>> getVertices();
}
```

This does compile

```
public interface D <Element>  {
    ArrayList <Element> getVertices();
}
```

When I run this code

```
public class G<Element> implements D<Element> {
    public ArrayList<Element> getVertices(){return null;}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        G <Element<String,Integer>> g = new G<>();
    }
}
```

I get this error.  'Error:(7, 12) java: non-static type variable Element cannot be referenced from a static context'

I'm not sure how to specify in the interface that I want all elements to have to be of the same type.

Comment: You seem to be confusing the class `Element` with a generic type that you created with the same name.

Comment: Thanks, you are correct, I was getting confused about where to put in element.  Solutions posted clarified.

Answer (score 2):

The `T1` and `T2` in your `D` interface are undefined, thats why you are getting compile error. The second `D` example is using row type of Element and thats why your `G <Element<String,Integer>>` declaration is wrong. Also you dont need to parametrize `G` at all.

Here is modified code that uses proper generics:

```
public interface D < T1 extends Comparable<T1>, T2  >  {

    ArrayList < Element<T1, T2> > getVertices();
}

public static class G implements D< String, Integer > {
    public ArrayList< Element<String, Integer> > getVertices(){return null;}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        G g = new G();
    }
}
```